# Calling an internal function inside a procedure PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

A bit green with PL/SQL functions but trying to add a function where if the current person does not have an alt_id to get the relative alt_id via the application.  Many thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLIENT.p_Verification(pin_Member_ID   IN dbo.member.member_id%Type,
                                                                 pin_Person_ID   IN dbo.person.person_id%type,
                                                                 pin_user_id     IN NUMBER default null,
                                                                 pioc_ref_cursor IN OUT dbo.pkg_benefit_q.ref_cursor) IS

lv_member_id         dbo.person.alt_identifier%Type;
-- other variables
...
Procedure p_get_other_deductions(...
Begin
...
end;
```

new function here

```
    FUNCTION f_get_alt_id 
         RETURN Varchar2 
         IS-- dbo.person.alt_identifier%Type IS
        alt_id Varchar2(10); --dbo.person.alt_identifier%Type;
    BEGIN        

      SELECT p.ALT_IDENTIFIER
        into alt_id
        FROM DBO.PERSON p , DBO.MEMBER m, DBO.APPLICATION a
      where p.PERSON_ID = m.PERSON_ID
        AND m.MEMBER_ID = a.MEMBER_ID
        AND a.APPLICATION_ID= cn_EntAppId
        ;

      RETURN alt_id;

    END;
```

calling it here...

```
  Select dbo.pkg_benefit_s.f_get_value_description('PREFIX',
                                                   p.prefix,
                                                   'Y',
                                                   'N') || case
           when p.prefix is not null then
            ' '
           else
            Null
         end || nvl2(p.first_name, initcap(p.first_name) || ' ', '') ||
         nvl2(p.middle_name, initcap(p.middle_name) || ' ', '') ||
         nvl2(p.last_name, initcap(p.last_name), '') || ' ' ||
         dbo.pkg_benefit_s.f_get_value_description('SUFFIX',
                                                   p.suffix,
                                                   'Y',
                                                   'N'),
         nvl2(p.alt_identifier, 
         f_get_alt_id, -- errors here
         ''), 
         nvl2(p.first_name, initcap(p.first_name), ''),
         nvl2(p.last_name, initcap(p.last_name), '')

    into lv_member_name,
         lv_member_id,
         lv_member_first_name,
         lv_member_last_name
    From dbo.person p
   where p.person_id = ln_person_id;
... more code 
END p_Verification;
/
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: the error was in calling the function later in the procedure and was preventing me from compiling the procedure. I posted a solution that enabled me to compile.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better practice in a number of ways to create a package that has your procedure and your function listed in the header and the body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CLIENT IS
PROCEDURE p_Verification(pin_Member_ID   IN dbo.member.member_id%Type,
                         pin_Person_ID   IN dbo.person.person_id%type,
                         pin_user_id     IN NUMBER default null,
                         pioc_ref_cursor IN OUT dbo.pkg_benefit_q.ref_cursor);
Procedure p_get_other_deductions(...
FUNCTION f_get_alt_id(alt_id_in IN NUMBER:= NULL)  RETURN Varchar2;
END CLIENT;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CLIENT IS

END CLIENT;
```

Notice how I have added a null parameter so if you need to redesign the function you can do so without invalidating any dependent objects.

Comment: The variable cn_EntAppId is calculated outside of the function and is used by other internal procedures and functions similar to how I am using it.

Comment: There are several internal procedures and another function declared in this procedure.  I placed the new function in that area, Toad recognizes it as a function under "Local Subprograms"

Comment: I like your solution however this is vendor code that is years old.  I dont have the heart to go in and rewrite the whole schema.  I did figure a solution though.  I will post that in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I added the 
`alt_id varchar(10)` in the declaration section

restored the select query above to simply return

```
     dbo.pkg_benefit_s.f_get_value_description('SUFFIX',
                                               p.suffix,
                                               'Y',
                                               'N'),
     p.alt_identifier,         
     nvl2(p.first_name, initcap(p.first_name), ''),
     nvl2(p.last_name, initcap(p.last_name), '')

into lv_member_name,
     lv_member_id,
     lv_member_first_name,
     lv_member_last_name
```

... everything else is the same...until

I added another section to set the lv_member_id

```
BEGIN

   Select p.alt_identifier
   into alt_id
   from dbo.person p
   where P.PERSON_ID = pin_Person_id;
   if alt_id is not null
   then
   lv_member_id := alt_id;
   else
   lv_member_id := f_get_alt_id;
   end if;   

   END;
```

... rest of procedure and end;  -- it now compiles